# HTML and PHP static website with email form and cleans the data

Tags: php, html

I've created a static website (clients request) and we have put a email form inside the contacts page. the form works well and sends the data but in the email that is received i get 
sam\'s clover\'s (Test Data) how to cleans the data in a static website to remove the \'s and just leave it as 's in the email.

I've tried looking with my keywords not really finding any luck based on the static parts.

any help would be great thanks 
This is the vars i'm using at the moment.

```
$to = STRIP_TAGS($_POST['remail']);      
$from = STRIP_TAGS($_POST['semail']);   
$phone = STRIP_TAGS($_POST['sphone']);  
$subject = STRIP_TAGS($_POST['subject']);    
$message = STRIP_TAGS($_POST['message']);   
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

Comment: If an answer has helped you, you must accept it aswell! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stripslashes()`:

It unquotes a quoted string. So `\'` becomes `'`.

```
$to = stripslashes($_POST['remail']);      
$from = stripslashes($_POST['semail']);   
$phone = stripslashes($_POST['sphone']);  
$subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);    
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);   
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

You can also use it for arrays:

```
stripslashes_deep($array_name);
```

Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, This worked well. Dynamic DB Websites I find much better, Thanks again

Comment: @Mohammad Don't get greedy over the answer button. With your score, you should realize that there is a time limit on the button.

Comment: @user2067005 I know, but when I saw his reputation I thought he wouldn't know that answer's could be accepted aswell because that's what I thought when I came first to this site! So just to tell him! :)

Comment: @Mohammad Alright, I see where you're coming from. It was just the way I read it :)

Comment: hack awway for quick fix, but not fix the root of the problem which is magic quotes...

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè I just gave him the solution he asked, I never give higher solutions because then sometimes the user gets confused! I thought of your's solution aswell but just stopped myself for posting it so that OP couldn't get confused!

Comment: @user2067005 Haha, No Problemo :)

Comment: I did, Just had to wait for the time to let me then was Away From Keyboard and just came back. Sorry for the delay in the accepting.

Answer (score 0):

What your after is [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), but if slashes are being added by PHP automatically from magic quotes then you should check for that, this way your script will run on any server, not just a server with magic quotes on.

Here is a callback function that will loop through all the effected Global vars and fix. You would add this as part of your initialization.

```
<?php 
function process_gpc(&$value, $key){
    //magic quotes fix
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $key   = stripslashes($key);
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    //null byte (string termination) protection
    $key   = str_replace(chr(0), '', $key);
    $value = str_replace(chr(0), '', $value);
}
$inputs = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST, &$_FILES);
array_walk_recursive($inputs, 'process_gpc');
?>
```